# What is the best way to show a created file to the user?

Tags: c#

I have this code for creating a ZIP file:

```
void Compress(string contentDirectory, string zippedFileDirectory)
{
    … // locate 7z.dll and invoke SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath
    SevenZipCompressor compressor = new SevenZipCompressor()
                                    {
                                        ArchiveFormat = OutArchiveFormat.Zip,
                                        CompressionMode = CompressionMode.Create,
                                        TempFolderPath = Path.GetTempPath()
                                    };
    string source = contentDirectory;
    string output = zippedFileDirectory;
    string zipFileName = "Diagnosis_Files.zip";
    string t = Path.Combine(output, zipFileName);
    compressor.CompressDirectory(source, t);
}
```

Right after `compressor.CompressDirectory` has finished creating the ZIP file, I want to show the ZIP file to the user so they can easily copy it or just see which directory it was created in.

How can I do this?

Comment: `Process.Start` with the filename should work

Comment: Sayse i tried this: Process.Start(t); but its just showing me the zip file content. not what i wanted.

Comment: Oh so you want to open the directory and show the files?

Comment: Sayse true , l4V answer is working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Process.Start("explorer", String.Format("/select,{0}", zipFileName));
```

---

```
Explorer [/n] [/e] [(,)/root,<object>] [/select,<object>]

/n                Opens a new single-pane window for the default
                  selection. This is usually the root of the drive Windows
                   is installed on. If the window is already open, a
                  duplicate opens.

/e                Opens Windows Explorer in its default view.

/root,<object>    Opens a window view of the specified object.


/select,<object>  Opens a window view with the specified folder, file or
                  application selected.

Examples:

   Example 1:     Explorer /select,C:\TestDir\TestApp.exe

      Opens a window view with TestApp selected.

   Example 2:  Explorer /e,/root,C:\TestDir\TestApp.exe

      This opens Explorer with C: expanded and TestApp selected.

   Example 3:  Explorer /root,\\TestSvr\TestShare

      Opens a window view of the specified share.

   Example 4:  Explorer /root,\\TestSvr\TestShare,select,TestApp.exe

      Opens a window view of the specified share with TestApp selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the "explorer.exe" process, providing the directory as its command line argument. Not sure however how to do this in a portable manner, so it would work also on Mono.

Answer (score 0):

The following line put at the end of your method will open the containing folder:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", output);
```